# PHP Save Image After imagecopyresampled

Tags: php, image

```
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```

How can i save the resized image to folder/ ?
And how can I detect the image type is jpg/png/gif?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To save the image to a file, you can use any of these: [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), [imagepng()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php), or [imagegif()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php), depending on your desired output format.

To detect the image type, you can just check the file's extension and base yourself on that. However, sometimes people manually change the extension of an image file, thinking that actually changes the image type, so it's always a good idea to check whether imagecreatefrom returned an image resource rather than false.

For a quick way to return just the extension of a file:

```
$ext = pathinfo($path_to_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

[Manual entry on pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Answer (score 6):

add this code

```
imagepng($iOut,'pic/mypic.png',3);
```

& this code to get your pics format from an external source

```
$link='http://example.com/example.png';
echo (substr ($link,strrpos ($link,".")+1));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define any type image:

```
 // Save the image as 'simpletext.jpg'
 imagejpeg($im, 'path/to/your/image.jpg');
 // or another image
 imagepng($im, 'path/to/your/image.png');
```

See examples here http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Answer (score 3):

```
$filename = 'path/to/original/file.xxx'; // where xxx is file type (jpg, gif, or png)
$newfilename = 'path/to/resized/file.xxx'; // where xxx is file type (jpg, gif, or png)
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
if ($path_parts['extension'] == 'jpg') {
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($image_p, $newfilename);
} elseif ($path_parts['extension'] == 'gif') {
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    imagegif($image_p, $newfilename);
} elseif ($path_parts['extension'] == 'png') {
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    imagepng($image_p, $newfilename);
} else {
        echo "Source file is not a supported image file type.";
}
```

Comment: Its working fine just creating issue with PNG file as the regenerated file need to be transparent. How it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

After you applied `imagecopyresampled()`, the `$dst_image` will be your image resource identifier.

Just applying the `imagecopyresampled()` function does not automagically also save it to the file system.

So you will need to save it, using one of the functions `imagejpeg()`, `imagepng()`

```
// Output
imagejpeg($dst_image, 'new-image.jpg', 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

to save image as jpg see imagejpeg function

http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

to get image extension use

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
echo $path_parts['extension'];
```