# How to resize image inside dir using php?

Tags: php, image

This is my code, for resize `test/15378596684270_1.jpg` from `136x136px` to `48x48px` but when test code , its' not resize any image how can i do ?

```
<?PHP
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$file = "test/15378596684270_1.jpg";
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);    
$newwidth = "48";
$newheight = "48";          
$image_info = getimagesize($file);  
if ($image_info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') { 
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
} elseif ($image_info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
    $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
} elseif ($image_info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
}       
$tgt = imagecreatetruecolor(48, 48);
imagecopyresampled($tgt, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
?>
```

Comment: How can you say? You're neither saving nor showing the image.

Comment: You'd need to save your image

Comment: yes i want to save a new image to 48x48px

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452650/php-save-image-after-imagecopyresampled

Comment: i fill `imagejpeg($file, $file, 100);` in last line but still not work,

Comment: at first, use full path in $file